# Raising specific exceptions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I have Python code that parses an XML to JSON. While it works correctly, I am looking to make it even more robust by raising some exceptions. Here is my current code:

```
    result['answer'].append({
        'multiplier': int(element.findall(r'Multiplier')[0].text), # This is an int
        'enabled': bool(element.attrib['enabled']), # This is bool
        'symbols': sym
    })
```

In the above code, I want to raise: XMLBooleanParsingError() if we cannot parse element.attrib['enabled'] to bool and XMLIntegerParsingError() if we cannot parse line #2.

I have tried multiple approaches like:

```
result['answer'].append({
    'multiplier': int(element.findall(r'Multiplier')[0].text), # This is an int
    try:
        'enabled': bool(element.attrib['enabled'])
    except:
        raise XMLBooleanParsingError()
    'symbols': sym
})
```

But I am getting errors. I want to catch exceptions while storing result in JSON. What are some approaches to follow?

Comment: Re *"I am getting errors"*: But not due to the trivial issue with the comment character? Was that in the original code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: Probably the simplest solution for that would be to create `parse_int` and `parse_bool` functions which would throw XMLBooleanParsingError.

Python doesn't have such syntax as you trying to employ, and I am even not sure if you can write `try/catch` blocks inside lambdas. Luckily, you can define functions everywhere, so that shouldn't be a problem.

```py
def parse_int(s: str) -> int:
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError as ex:
        raise XMLIntParsingError from ex # gives more verbose and comprehendible exception message
```

On a side note, doing `bool(s)` is most probably not how you want to parse bools, since `bool("false") == True` and `bool("0") == True`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use try-except like that. The append command needs to be in the "try" block of the try-except, and not inside the dictionary definition.

```
try:
    result['answer'].append({
        'multiplier': int(element.findall(r'Multiplier')[0].text), 
        'enabled': bool(element.attrib['enabled']),
        'symbols': sym
    })
except:
    raise XMLBooleanParsingError()
```

I think it would be better to parse the arguments separately, see if there are exceptions raised during the parsing, and only insert to the dictionary if everything succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

This is the better approach if you want individual exception for each parsing:

```
try:
    multi = int(element.findall(r'Multiplier')[0].text)
except exception as e:
    raise [your exception]()
try:
    enable = bool(element.attrib['enabled'])
except exception as e:
    raise [your exception]()
result['answer'].append({
    'multiplier':multi  , // This is an int
    'enabled': enable , // This is bool
    'symbols': sym
})
```

You could do it in one go but you will need to know what exception are you trying to catch:

```
try:
    multi = int(element.findall(r'Multiplier')[0].text)
    raise [your exception]()
    enable = bool(element.attrib['enabled'])
    result['answer'].append({
    'multiplier':multi  , // This is an int
    'enabled': enable , // This is bool
    'symbols': sym
    })
except [first exception] as e:
    raise [your exception]()
except [second exception] as e:
    raise [your exception]()
```